# Replaced the curser to while loop but not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me.
I have changed the Curser to While loop due to performance issue.

But my while loop is not working , infact its taking longer then usual and also it seems its going for infinite loop , please let me know what I am doing mistake here.

Using Curser - Working Fine

```
DECLARE policyVerify_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
Select AccountId, PolicyNumber, IsPolicyBalance, Remarks from @VerifyPolicyNumbers

-- Open cursor
OPEN policyVerify_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM policyVerify_cursor INTO @AccountId, @PolicyNumber, @IsPolicyBalance, @Remarks

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS= 0)
BEGIN

 -- my LOGIC
    FETCH NEXT FROM policyVerify_cursor
    INTO @AccountId, @PolicyNumber, @IsPolicyBalance, @Remarks

END
```

My Query Using While loop - Not working

```
DECLARE @NumberRecords int, @RowCounter int
SET @NumberRecords = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @VerifyPolicyNumbers)

SET @RowCounter = 1

-- loop through all records in the temporary table
-- using the WHILE loop construct
WHILE @RowCounter <= @NumberRecords
BEGIN
-- My Logic
SET @RowCounter = @RowCounter + 1
END
```

Comment: What happens when you make what goes in "My Logic" empty.  Does the loop end quickly?  Also, I don't know why your change might improve performance, but I assume it's not critical to your question right now.

Comment: Thanks for response, I believe its some issue with @NumberRecords count, can you please how to fix that. I mean count is keep on increasing in that way its going to infinite loop. some problem with this line -(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @VerifyPolicyNumbers)

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that implies an infinite loop.  Whatever is wrong, its got to do with whatever is happening in "My Logic", which you don't show.

Comment: My Logic code is too big, its same code as present using Curser, that works fine, without any issue . But same thing I changed using WHIEL loop that's going to infinite loop

Comment: Why do you change the cursor with another cursor (but one that you write yourself)? If you want to improve performance you'll need to use set based operations.

Comment: You really need to edit your question to add a minimally reproducible example of what's going on in "My Logic", because your problem is in there.  But I have a hunch as to what's going on, so I took a stab at the answer.  Let me know if I'm off base with it.

Comment: Deleted my answer, since it seemed off base.  Please edit your question to make the symptom of infinite loops reproducible.  As it stands, your example does not produce the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I have no idea where your @VerifyPolicyNumbers table comes from that your declared cursor is coming from.  Also, if the @VerifyPolicyNumbers table is something you are adding into while doing your logic, is THAT causing some of the problems... more records after you declared the list?

You might want to pull your query into a TEMPORARY SESSION table with "#" and query from that so you don't run into the possible scenario I described first.  Then adjust something like

```
select
      AccountId, 
      PolicyNumber, 
      IsPolicyBalance, 
      Remarks 
   into
      #myTempList
   from 
      @VerifyPolicyNumbers


DECLARE policyVerify_cursor CURSOR 
-- declaring the cursor for SCROLLING THROUGH RECORDS
SCROLL FOR
Select 
      AccountId, 
      PolicyNumber, 
      IsPolicyBalance, 
      Remarks 
   from 
      #myTempList

-- Open cursor
OPEN policyVerify_cursor

-- explicitly select FIRST record
FETCH FIRST FROM policyVerify_cursor INTO 
   @AccountId, @PolicyNumber, @IsPolicyBalance, @Remarks

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS= 0)
BEGIN

   -- my LOGIC
   -- Now, get the NEXT record.
   FETCH NEXT FROM policyVerify_cursor
      INTO @AccountId, @PolicyNumber, @IsPolicyBalance, @Remarks

END 

CLOSE policyVerify_cursor
DEALLOCATE policyVerify_cursor
```

It may be failing since you did not declare cursor FOR SCROLL, also FETCHING FIRST record to start the cycle